# How to find memory usage difference in Grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-alerts

I am working in graph panel in grafana and using elastic search as a data source. In the data source, I have memory-used with timestamp. I am trying to give notification alert when the difference is more than 100 MB. How to find memory difference between the memory used in day one and memory used in current day and send alert notification?

Answer (score 0):

You would setup a query which is basically grouped by timestamp and define it based on whether you are looking for the 100 MB difference to be on max value or average. Assuming it is max value- you query would be something like
[image: https://play.grafana.org/d/000000014/elasticsearch-metrics?tab=query&editPanel=1]

And then you would set alerts by going to the alert tab based on the query and diff in the values for 24 hours

[image: https://play.grafana.org/d/000000014/elasticsearch-metrics?tab=alert&editPanel=1]